# Why does jslint error when checking variable definitions within code blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I have the following code:

```
         $('#modal .update-title')
            .change(function () {
                var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
                $(this).prop('title', title);

                // For the question screen, after the initial set up 
                // changes move the title to the title input field.
                if ($(this).data('propagate-title') === 'yes') {
                    var m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/);
                    if (m) {
                        $("#modal_Title_" + m[1]).val(title);
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I run jslint it gives me the following error:

```
   Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.
   var m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/);
```

is jslint wrong or am I wrong?

Comment: Blocks do *not* introduce a new scope in JavaScript and the inner `var` is "hoisted". JSLint is telling you that someone (e.g. Crockford) therefor thinks that all local variable declarations should all be put at the *top* of the function-block in a *single* `var` statement. (I do not agree with either "style" guideline, nor do I support JSLint -- perhaps there is an option to make JSLint validate *valid* code according to your guidelines/style?)

Comment: (JSLint is *opinionated software*. It will "error" on some perfectly valid syntax constructs. Use the tool with that in mind: it is *your* code.)

Comment: @pst - Thanks for the comment. You mention that blocks do not introduce a new scope. Does that even apply to variables declared inside functions? If I have a .js file with a function and then several functions inside that is every variable declaration hoisted to the top?

Comment: Only function [blocks] introduce a new function scope; *local variables exist as part of a function scope* and no other block construct introduces a new function scope. `var` is hoisted to the top of the most *inner* function block/scope. (Non-scoping constructs, because they are not function blocks, include: `{}` [actually the generic form of all of the other syntax blocks], `if(){..}`, `for(){..}`, `while(){..}`, `with(){..}`, etc.)

Comment: It should be noted that the generic block `{..}` and the braces found in a function declaration are *not* the same. For instance, `if (true) alert("x")` is valid, but `function () alert("x")` is not -- the braces are *part* of the function declaration syntax itself and do not constitute a "block" in the more general sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using the if condition does not create a new scope. so the variable m only exist if the condition is true. So here is what you can do

```
$('#modal .update-title').change(function () {
    var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title'),
    m = null; // or just m;
    $(this).prop('title', title);

    // For the question screen, after the initial set up 
    // changes move the title to the title input field.
    if ($(this).data('propagate-title') === 'yes') {
        m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/);
        if (m) {
            $("#modal_Title_" + m[1]).val(title);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this is the "why", I cannot up-vote because I am opposed to JSLints (read: Crockfords) view of the world in topics like this. I would *not* alter the code presented in the post in this fashion. JSLint can go bugger off (or be configured with the appropriate option, should it exist).

Comment: If you are coming here in 2020 and find this weird, well now you can use the keyword `let` instead of `var` inside the condition. Unlike var, `let` will create a new scope inside the condition.